# onNewIntent not being fired

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle, url-scheme

I'm using intent filter for catching a custom scheme for my app:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/title_my_activity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">

    <!-- myapp://app.open -->
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/my_intent">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data android:scheme="myapp" />
        <data android:host="app" />
        <data android:host="app.open" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my activity I override:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", "New intent!");
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
}
```

but this is never called...where am I wrong?
Is noHistory flag necessary? If I remove that, I've two copies of the same activity on the stack.

Comment: how about using `android:launchMode="singleTask"`?

Comment: Seems to work, except that onResume is being called twice...could you please elaborate why in an answer? Many thanks.

Comment: Do ytou have other activities in your app?

Answer (score 0):

**Below code is working fine for me**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data android:scheme="myapp" />
            <data android:host="app" />
            <data android:host="app.open" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Log.d("DEBUG", "New intent!");
}}
```